# Fixing the valves on tubeless tires broke, what are my options?

Tags: maintenance, valves, tubeless

I bought a used bike that was set up with tubeless wheels, however both valves are shot what should I do?  In general, is there more maintenance involved with the upkeep of tubeless wheels? Because I'm thinking of just throwing some tubes in there and call it good.

Comment: what do you mean by 'valves are shot'? any tubeless valve is going to have replaceable valve cores, so that is easy enough. If the valves themselves are stripped, it's still just removing the tire (as you would for a flat fix) and replacing the entire valve. This would require a compressor or something similar to reseat the tire most likely.

Comment: The one presta valve has the little stem thing missing and the other presta valve seems to leak air even when i have it screwed down tight and closed... i can still add air with it but it is also leaking the air right back.  I do have a little compressor, but i probably need a presta chuck for my compressor to reseat it?

Comment: Adding tubes should fix your problem, assuming the rims and tyres are tube-compatible and are not tubeless-only.

Comment: @eric you would need a presta chuck or a presta adapter as seen here http://fcdn.mtbr.com/attachments/29er-components/818519d1359601749-presta-valve-chuck-air-compressor-presta-adapter.jpg

Comment: How could a tubeless-only tire work?

Comment: Entire new tubeless valve stems aren't expensive, they're about the same price as a new tube. You can also DIY them from an old tube more or less for free.

Comment: @EricSwiggum - Are you sure the valves are what is leaking (for the wheel with the intact valve). Tubeless systems also require a liquid sealant placed in your tires that will help seal any minor leaks (e.g., punctures and rim/tire connection).  If you have a fairly large tire you will also need a good burst of air to get tire to seal to the rim (e.g., CO2 cartridge) as a track pump may not move enough air fast enough.  Tubeless can be a bit of a learning curve, but can really improve the ride and traction.

Comment: Jamie A, can you elaborate on how someone can DIY them from an old tube, I would be interested in how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the wrench flats on the valve core are still accessible, you should be able to replace just the valve core:

[image: presta valve]

*from https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/36955/30982*

[image: presta valve in pieces]

*http://k0lee.com/2009/10/putting-tire-sealant-in-presta-valve-tubes/*

If there is leaking, you could spray some soapy water around the valve to see where its leaking from. If its leaking between the valve and the rim, possibly the valve is not tight enough. To tighten: from inside the rim, push the valve 'outward' (towards hub) and tighten down lockring by hand. Never tighten with a wrench as you'll never be able to remove it on the trail! (I've learned the hard way).

As far as 'is tubeless worth it?' or 'is it more complicated?' that will be largely opinion based and an internet search will likely turn up countless discussion. A simple answer would be: do what lets you ride your dang bike. If you're familiar with tubes, throw some tubes in there and go shred. some winter if you're looking for a project, get a friend who is more familiar with it and give it a go.